# Error in data insertion in heroku psql table using heroku CLI

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert, string-constant

I am using Heroku CLI to insert data in a database table. I have table name `review` and these are the columns of it :- (date,verified_reveiws,total_reviews). You can see it in provided image also. when I am executing insert command `INSERT INTO review (date,verified_reveiws,total_reviews) VALUES (December, 5, 1169);` i am getting this error `ERROR:  column "december" does not exist`, `LINE 1: ...iew (date,verified_reveiws,total_reviews) VALUES (December, ...`. I didn't able to get why this error is coming. `psql` version I am using is `12.5`.[image]

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Comment: Thanks to all of you! It's work!

Comment: ok! I will not post code as images. Thanks!